# Combine merge content in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, cell-format

Are there any formulas or tricks to change the cell formatting from the red table to the green table in Excel 2016?

[image: Please see the picture first]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1):

To merge cells, I think you need Macros, the following steps are not clever, when the amount of data is not large, it can be used as a workaround.

I made a sample as your red table on my test environment, the add a column and enter `=LOOKUP(1,0/(A$2:A2<>""),A$2:A2)` in C2 to get values for help.

[image]

Then copy cells from A2 to C9 to other location,such as cells from D2 to D9. Then enter `=PHONETIC(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(C2,$C$2:$C$9,),,COUNTIF($C$2:$C$9,C2)))` in E2.

[image]

To merge cells, I go to Developer tab > Record Macro > Give a short cut for it, make a demo of merging cells > Stop recording.

And then I choose the cells in column E with same data and press shortcut to run macro to merge cells, and only upper-left value is left.

[image]